# Cos'è questa "giostra"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Mi facevo assorbire dalle 
>   assonanze. Sulla tavola di Natale il campanellino della **giostra** mossa dalle candele accese mi rimandava al tintinnio delle stazioni di periferia quando è in arrivo un treno; alle stazioni quel suono mi rimandava alla tavola di Natale.

Non so cos'è questa "giostra" di cui parla l'autore. Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che alcune di queste giostre si possono comprare su Internet. Ma in cosa consistono esattamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se sono quelle che penso io, sono delle decorazioni, per lo più appunto natalizie, in cui l'aria calda fatta sollevare per convezione da alcune candeline colpisce una leggera ruota orizzontale formata da pale diagonali in legno o metallo, facendola girare. La ruota, a sua volta, fa girare altri piccoli elementi appesi: angioletti, bacchettine che urtano dei campanellini e così via.

[image: Giostrina]

(Ovviamente, guardandola per un secondo, soprattutto dal vivo, dovrebbe essere tutto più chiaro che leggendone una descrizione analitica.)